# jcarousel circular mode, variable starting position

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I have a problem with setting a starting position, that depends on the class of item that has been clicked.

I have two lists:

1) List of previews with classes in -tags (class="1", class="2"...);

2) jcarousel list of the same items.

Second list is hidden. When user clicks at any item of the first list, the script hides first list and shows second. Also it gets the clicked item class and passes it to the jcarousel initialisation code.

```
$('.itemsinner A').click(function() {
    var height = $('.preview_list').height();
    var item = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.preview_list').animate({height: 0}, 1000, function() {
        $('.slider').animate({height: 500}, 1000);
    });
    $('#carousel').jcarousel({
        wrap: 'circular',
        scroll: 1,
        visible: 1,
        start: item
    });
    return false;
});
```

If I define start parameter for jcarousel not variable "item", but some number it all works ok. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Forgot to mention: when start parameter is "item", jcarousel starts with correct item, but when I scroll it, it shows the same item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be a data type mismatch?  Class = "1", so 'item' is a string.  Does jcarousel expect a numeric value instead?  Try

```
start: parseInt(item, 10)
```

Comment: Awesome job, that helped me too. Really should have thought of that!